# Is it possible to access a local file from a browser on a mobile device?

Tags: javascript, android, mobile, browser

Question:
Let's say I create an android game that saves a save file(in the form of a text file) on the local android internal storage and I know the absolute path where the file is saved. Is it possible to create a website with a built in script that retrieves this textfile and displays the save data to the user? If not, why and are there any unconventional ways to get around it?

From my own research, I have seen similar topics give pretty mixed results. Some say that the browser is sandboxed, while others say that it's now possible. Any clarification would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why isn't your game app displaying the score to the user?

Comment: I'm proposing a hypothetical situation, where if I made a android game that saves a text file in the local directory. If a user accesses my website, I'm asking if it is possible for the browser to have a built in script to access the textfile, so that I can display and manipulate the data on my website. 

For instance: Let's say I made an android version of tic tac toe, and the user has one win, which is saved in a textfile in his phone. When the user accesses my website, can I write a script so my website retrieves the text file and display "you have 1 win"? If you need more info please ask!

Comment: `If a user accesses my website`. Your website is on the internet? The user uses a browser on a pc? Or a browser on the same android device as your game? What has manipulating data on your website to do with this all? `so that I can display and manipulate the data on my website`. I dont know how that would look like  'displaying data on a website' but if you mean display data in the browser?

Comment: The user accesses their browser on the same android device. By "display the data on a website", I meant display the data in the browser. I feel that my analogy may have overcomplicated the question at hand. This all should boil down to a yes no question: "If I have a text file located in the internal storage on an android device, is there a way to access the file from within the browser using a web based script (given the browser is accessed on the same device)?" I apologize for the confusion. Thanks for bearing with me.

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible if you have a local web server running on your Android Device. If you can save the file to the Web Server Document folder, you can then access the file from your browser. I haven't tried it, but it sounds logically possible.

Comment: I'm a bit iffy using a local web server as I would like the code to work so that when any user with the text file accesses the site, they will be able to see their score from they're individual textfile. The problem is that not everyone is going to have local web server running on their android device. Thank you so much for your input!